# Sleep between calls of Mail() in PHP

Tags: php, email, sleep

How would i send an email, to say 3000 recipients - with a Max 500 emails / hours on my dedicated IP? So far my thought is to send each email every 9 seconds, this would come to about 450 emails an hour... but how could i do this?

My plan for the sending of the emails would be the following...

```
$emails = ARRAY OF EMAILS, MYSQL RESULT
for($emails){
mail($subject,$row[email],$headers);
}
```

This wont work, wrong kind of statement but this concept anyway....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What I would do is :

- create a PHP script that is launched via cron once per hour
- this script only sends 450 e-mails, at its own speed
- when the 450 mails are sent, the script dies
- and some time later, it is re-launched, by cron, to send 450 other mails.

The trick is : you have to know which mails where already sent.

Ordering the mails by id in your DB, or something like that, and using limit, would be OK, I suppose

If you want to sleep for a while between mails, use the [`sleep`](http://php.net/sleep) function ; something between 2 and 5 seconds would probably be OK, to be sure you script the chunk of 450 mails is finished before the script is re-launched by cron.

And, thinking about it :

- You should put some logging stuff in place : if someone complains, saying he received 10 emails, it could help you find out why.
- I wouldn't use the `mail` function : there are plenty of other possibilities, using libraries that are well-tested and provide lots of functionnalities, already developped : don't re-invent the wheel ;-)

Here are a couple of libraries I can think about :

- [Swift Mailer](http://swiftmailer.org/)
- [`Zend_Mail`](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.mail.html)
- [PHPMailer](http://www.phpclasses.org/browse/package/264.html)
- [`PEAR::Mail`](http://pear.php.net/package/Mail)
- [Rmail](http://www.phpguru.org/static/mime.mail.html)

Comment: SwiftMailer ships with a plugin called "Throttler", take a look at its documentation at http://swiftmailer.org/docs/throttler-plugin-howto

Answer (score 2):

Store You messages for sending in a database, mark messages which are sent.
In a cron job select some of them that are not sent, and process them.
The frequency of the cron job determines the speed of sending the emails.

Comment: to user asking: moreover, you can not let PHP script run indefinitely - most servers will limit script run time.

Answer (score 1):

[SwiftMailer](http://swiftmailer.org/) does it this for you:

- http://swiftmailer.org/docs/antiflood-plugin
- http://swiftmailer.org/docs/throttler-plugin

Answer (score 0):

You could use this very handy Timer class to do the heavy lifting for you (start, stop and get the elapsed time within your loop, etc): [PHPClasses: Timer.php](http://www.phpclasses.org/browse/file/1378.html).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the answers!
The best way i found was actually to simply sleep() between calls using the sleep() as i tested 400 mails, this took 17 seconds :)

It is unlikely the user will send more than the 450 limit ... but if they do i have an if statement before the while() ends checking if there are more than 450 rows, if so it will sleep between each... this works without fiddly databases :)

Thanks!